# How to put the object I get from input in an JSON array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object, config

I'm doing a weather forecasting console app. I ask the user if they want to save the input location. When they enter longitude and latitude, it is saved in JSON file, so later on(on the second try) they can just select the city from the list. The problem is that when the city object is saved in a JSON file, it is not in an array, which is why later on I don't get the list displayed.

Program.cs

```
//saving city objcet in JSON file
            if (userLoc == 1)
            {
                IConfiguration citConfiguration = new Configuration("cities.json");
                var CitiesConfig = new City()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    CityName = $"{weatherInfo.Timezone}",
                    Lng = weatherInfo.Longitude,
                    Lat = weatherInfo.Latitude
                };
                citConfiguration.SetConfigs(CitiesConfig);
            }
```

City.cs

```
using Weather.PCL.Models.Abstractions;
using Configs.Models.Abstractions;

namespace Weather.PCL.Models.Implementations
{
    public class City : ICity, IConfig
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public double Lng { get; set; }
        public double Lat { get; set; }
    }
}
```

setting config

```
public bool SetConfigs(IConfig config)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_path))
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);
                sw.Write(json);

                sw.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

displaying the list of cities in JSON file

```
var citiesJson = configuration.GetConfigs();
                var citiesArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City[]>(citiesJson);

                foreach (var item in citiesArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Id + ". " + item.CityName);
                }
```

When I run the project I get an exception `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Weather.PCL.Models.Implementations.City[]'`

What can I do?

Comment: You are deserializing an object to array... provide json for definitive answer

Comment: json is empty at the start

Comment: Your json should be `[]` if you want it to be empty. It can't be {}

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string do not contain JSON array .
Make sure your JSON string look like this: `[{"aaa":"a1","bbb":"b1","ccc":null},{"aaa":"a2","bbb":"b2","ccc":null}]`

Comment: it only saves a new city if JSON file is empty, so this won't help

Comment: Error you get is indicating exactly what I am saying, but it's up to u, of course, believe it or not.:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one city you have to create array of cities

```
 var CitiesConfig = new City[] {  
        new City
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    CityName = $"{weatherInfo.Timezone}",
                    Lng = weatherInfo.Longitude,
                    Lat = weatherInfo.Latitude
                }
               };
```

to write

```
public bool SetConfigs(City[] config)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"cities.json"))
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config);
                sw.Write(json);

                sw.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and to test

```
string json = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"cities.json"))
        json = r.ReadToEnd();
        
    var citiesArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<City[]>(json);

    foreach (var item in citiesArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Id + ". " + item.CityName);
    }
```